# Receive and display response notifications from gateway on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a plugin built to integrate a payment gateway into wordpress woocommerce.
Its working ok but when the response comes from the gateway I don't know how to get and 
display it within wordpress. Here is the plugin code:

```
    function sb_gtpay_init() {
    if (!class_exists('WC_Payment_Gateway')) {
        return;
    }

    class WC_GTPay extends WC_Payment_Gateway { 

        public function __construct() { 
            global $woocommerce;

            $this->id       = 'gtpay';
            $this -> icon  =  plugins_url( 'GTPay.png' , __FILE__ );
            $this->has_fields   = false;
            $this->liveurl      = 'https://ibank.gtbank.com/GTPay/Tranx.aspx';
            $this->method_title     = __( 'GTPay', 'woocommerce' );

            // Load the form fields.
            $this->init_form_fields();

            // Load the settings.
            $this->init_settings();

            // Define user set variables
            $this->title        = $this->settings['title'];
            $this->description  = $this->settings['description'];
            $this->marchant_id  = $this->settings['marchant_id'];   
            $this->hash_key     = $this->settings['hash_key'];  
            $this->thanks_message   = $this->settings['thanks_message'];    
            $this->error_message    = $this->settings['error_message']; 
            $this->feedback_message = '';
            $this->response_codes   = $this->get_response_codes();

            // Actions
            add_action( 'init', array(&$this, 'check_ipn_response') );
            add_action('valid-gtpay-ipn-request', array(&$this, 'successful_request') );
            add_action('woocommerce_receipt_gtpay', array(&$this, 'receipt_page'));
            //add_action('woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways', array(&$this, 'process_admin_options'));

            //add_action('woocommerce_thankyou_' . $this->id, array(&$this, 'thankyou_page'));


            // Actions
            if ( version_compare( WOOCOMMERCE_VERSION, '2.0', '<' ) ) {
                // Pre 2.0
                add_action('woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways', array(&$this, 'process_admin_options'));
            } else {
                // 2.0
                add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );
            }           

            //Filters
            add_filter('woocommerce_currencies', array($this, 'add_ngn_currency'));
            add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', array($this, 'add_ngn_currency_symbol'), 10, 2);

            if ( !$this->is_valid_for_use() ) $this->enabled = false;

        }

        function add_ngn_currency($currencies) {
             $currencies['NGN'] = __( 'Nigerian Naira (NGN)', 'woocommerce' );
             return $currencies;
        }

        function add_ngn_currency_symbol($currency_symbol, $currency) {
            switch( $currency ) {
                case 'NGN':
                    $currency_symbol = '₦';
                    break;
            }

            return $currency_symbol;
        }    

        function is_valid_for_use() {
            $return = true;

            if (!in_array(get_option('woocommerce_currency'), array('NGN'))) {
                $return = false;
            }

            return $return;
        }

        function admin_options() {

            echo '<h3>' . __('GTPay', 'woocommerce') . '</h3>';
            echo '<p>' . __('GTPay works by sending the user to secured GTBank portal to enter their payment information.', 'woocommerce') . '</p>';
            echo '<table class="form-table">';

            if ( $this->is_valid_for_use() ) {
                $this->generate_settings_html();
            } else {
                echo '<div class="inline error"><p><strong>' . __( 'Gateway Disabled', 'woocommerce' ) . '</strong>: ' . __( 'GTPay does not support your store currency.', 'woocommerce' ) . '</p></div>';
            }

            echo '</table>';

        }

           function init_form_fields() {
            $this->form_fields = array(
                'enabled' => array(
                                'title' => __( 'Enable/Disable', 'woocommerce' ), 
                                'type' => 'checkbox', 
                                'label' => __( 'Enable GTPay', 'woocommerce' ), 
                                'default' => 'yes'
                            ), 
                'title' => array(
                                'title' => __( 'Title', 'woocommerce' ), 
                                'type' => 'text', 
                                'description' => __( 'This controls the title which the user sees during checkout.', 'woocommerce' ), 
                                'default' => __( 'GTPay', 'woocommerce' )
                            ),
                'description' => array(
                                'title' => __( 'Description', 'woocommerce' ), 
                                'type' => 'textarea', 
                                'description' => __( 'This controls the description which the user sees during checkout.', 'woocommerce' ), 
                                'default' => __("Pay via GTPay;", 'woocommerce')
                            ),
                'thanks_message' => array(
                                'title' => __( 'Thanks message', 'woocommerce' ), 
                                'type' => 'textarea', 
                                'description' => __( 'The message to show on a successful payment', 'woocommerce' ), 
                                'default' => __("Thank you. Your order has been received", 'woocommerce')
                            ),
                'error_message' => array(
                                'title' => __( 'Failure message', 'woocommerce' ), 
                                'type' => 'textarea', 
                                'description' => __( 'The message to show when a payment has failed', 'woocommerce' ), 
                                'default' => __("Sorry. There was a problem with your order", 'woocommerce')
                            ),
                'marchant_id' => array(
                                'title' => __( 'Marchant ID', 'woocommerce' ), 
                                'type' => 'text', 
                                'description' => __( 'This is the GTPay-wide unique identifier of merchant, assigned by GTPay and communicated to merchant by GTBank.', 'woocommerce' ), 
                                'default' => ''
                            ),
                'hash_key' => array(
                                'title' => __( 'Hash Key', 'woocommerce' ), 
                                'type' => 'text', 
                                'description' => __( 'Hash Key is a hash which would have been given to you when you opened your account with GTPay', 'woocommerce' ), 
                                'default' => ''
                            )
            );

        }

        function payment_fields() {
            if ($this->description) {
            echo wpautop(wptexturize($this->description));
            }
        }

        function get_gtpay_args( $order ) {
            global $woocommerce;

            $order_id = wp_rand(1, 9999977);
            $redirect_url = $this->get_return_url($order);
            $order_total = round(((number_format($order->get_order_total() + $order->get_order_discount(), 2, '.', ''))*100),0);
            $hash_string = $order_id . $order_total  . $redirect_url . $this->hash_key;
            $hash = hash('sha512', $hash_string);

            $gtpay_args = array(
                'gtpay_mert_id'             => $this->marchant_id,
                'gtpay_tranx_id'            => $order_id,
                'gtpay_tranx_amt'           => $order_total,
                'gtpay_tranx_curr'          => 566,
                'gtpay_tranx_memo'                       =>"Mobow",

                'gtpay_tranx_hash'          => $hash,


                'gtpay_tranx_noti_url'          => $redirect_url,
                'gtpay_cust_id'         => $order_id . wp_rand(1, 999999),
                'gtpay_cust_name'           => trim($order->billing_first_name . ' ' . $order->billing_last_name)


            );

            if (isset($order->user_id)) {
                $gtpay_args['gtpay_cust_id'] = $order->user_id;
            }

            $gtpay_args = apply_filters('woocommerce_gtpay_args', $gtpay_args);

            return $gtpay_args;
        }

        function generate_gtpay_form( $order_id ) {
            global $woocommerce;

            $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
            $gtpay_args = $this->get_gtpay_args( $order );
            $gtpay_args_array = array();

            $gtpay_adr = $this->liveurl;

            foreach ($gtpay_args as $key => $value) {
                $gtpay_args_array[] = '<input type="hidden" name="' . esc_attr($key) . '" value="' . esc_attr($value) . '" />';
            }


            $woocommerce->add_inline_js('
                jQuery("body").block({ 
                    message: "<img src=\"'.esc_url( $woocommerce->plugin_url() ).'/assets/images/ajax-loader.gif\" alt=\"Redirecting...\" style=\"float:left; margin-right: 10px;\" />'.__('Thank you for your order. We are now redirecting you to GTPay to make payment.', 'woocommerce').'", 
                    overlayCSS: { 
                        background: "#fff", 
                        opacity: 0.6 
                    },
                    css: { 
                        padding:        20, 
                        textAlign:      "center", 
                        color:          "#555", 
                        border:         "3px solid #aaa", 
                        backgroundColor:"#fff", 
                        cursor:         "wait",
                        lineHeight: "32px"
                    } 
                });
                jQuery("#submit_gtpay_payment_form").click();
            ');

            $form = '<form action="'.esc_url( $gtpay_adr ).'" method="post" id="gtpay_payment_form">
                    ' . implode('', $gtpay_args_array) . '
                    <input type="submit" class="button-alt" id="submit_gtpay_payment_form" value="'.__('Pay via GTPay', 'woocommerce').'" /> <a class="button cancel" href="'.esc_url( $order->get_cancel_order_url() ).'">'.__('Cancel order &amp; restore cart', 'woocommerce').'</a>
                </form>';
                echo $form; exit;

            return $form;
        }

        function generate_gtpay_try_again_form( $order_id ) {
            global $woocommerce;

            $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
            $gtpay_args = $this->get_gtpay_args( $order );
            $gtpay_args_array = array();

            $gtpay_adr = $this->liveurl;

            foreach ($gtpay_args as $key => $value) {
                $gtpay_args_array[] = '<input type="hidden" name="' . esc_attr($key) . '" value="' . esc_attr($value) . '" />';
            }

            $form = '<form action="'.esc_url( $gtpay_adr ).'" method="post" id="gtpay_payment_form">
                    ' . implode('', $gtpay_args_array) . '
                    <input type="submit" class="button-alt" id="submit_gtpay_payment_form" value="'.__('Try Again', 'woocommerce').'" />
                </form>';

            return $form;
        }

        function successful_request( $posted ) {
            global $woocommerce;
            print_r($_GET); exit;
            $order_ref = $posted['gtpay_tranx_id'];
            $order = new WC_Order( (int) $order_ref );



            //fool the thanks page into working?
            $_GET['key'] = $order->order_key;
            $_GET['order'] - $order->id;

            if ($this->get_transaction_status($order_ref)) {
                // Check order not already completed
                if ($order->status == 'completed') :
                     return false;
                endif;

                // Payment completed
                $order->add_order_note( __('IPN payment completed', 'woocommerce') );
                $order->payment_complete();
                $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();

                foreach ($_GET as $k=>$v) {
                    update_post_meta((int)$order_ref, $k, $v);
                }

                update_post_meta( (int) $order_ref, 'Payment Method', 'GTPay');

                $this->feedback_message = $this->thanks_message;
            } else {
                $error_code = '';
                if (@$_GET['resp']) {
                    $error_code = $this->response_codes[$_GET['resp']];
                }

                $try_again = $this->generate_gtpay_try_again_form($this->parse_txn_ref_order_id($order_ref));

                $order->add_order_note(__('Payment Failed - ' . $error_code, 'woocommerce'));
                $order->update_status('failed');

                $woocommerce->add_error('Transaction Failed: ' . $error_code . ' ' . $try_again); // Transaction Failed Notice on Checkout

                $this->feedback_message = $this->failed_message . $error_code . ' ' . $try_again;

            }
        }

        function thankyou_page() {
            echo wpautop($this->feedback_message);
        }

        public function get_response_codes() {
            return array(
                '00'=>'Approved by Financial Institution'
                ,'01'=>'Refer to Financial Institution'
                ,'02'=>'Refer to Financial Institution, Special Condition'
                ,'03'=>'Invalid Merchant'
                ,'04'=>'Pick-up card'
                ,'05'=>'Do Not Honor'
                ,'06'=>'Error'
                ,'07'=>'Pick-Up Card, Special Condition'
                ,'08'=>'Honor with Identification'
                ,'09'=>'Request in Progress'
                ,'10'=>'Approved by Financial Institution, Partial'
                ,'11'=>'Approved by Financial Institution, VIP'
                ,'12'=>'Invalid Transaction'
                ,'13'=>'Invalid Amount'
                ,'14'=>'Invalid Card Number'
                ,'15'=>'No Such Financial Institution'
                ,'16'=>'Approved by Financial Institution, Update Track 3'
                ,'17'=>'Customer Cancellation'
                ,'18'=>'Customer Dispute'
                ,'19'=>'Re-enter Transaction'
                ,'20'=>'Invalid Response from Financial Institution'
                ,'21'=>'No Action Taken by Financial Institution'
                ,'22'=>'Suspected Malfunction'
                ,'23'=>'Unacceptable Transaction Fee'
                ,'24'=>'File Update not Supported'
                ,'25'=>'Unable to Locate Record'
                ,'26'=>'Duplicate Record'
                ,'27'=>'File Update Field Edit Error'
                ,'28'=>'File Update File Locked'
                ,'29'=>'File Update Failed'
                ,'30'=>'Format Error'
                ,'31'=>'Bank Not Supported'
                ,'32'=>'Completed Partially by Financial Institution'
                ,'33'=>'Expired Card, Pick-Up'
                ,'34'=>'Suspected Fraud, Pick-Up'
                ,'35'=>'Contact Acquirer, Pick-Up'
                ,'36'=>'Restricted Card, Pick-Up'
                ,'37'=>'Call Acquirer Security, Pick-Up'
                ,'38'=>'PIN Tries Exceeded, Pick-Up'
                ,'39'=>'No Credit Account'
                ,'40'=>'Function not Supported'
                ,'41'=>'Lost Card, Pick-Up'
                ,'42'=>'No Universal Account'
                ,'43'=>'Stolen Card, Pick-Up'
                ,'44'=>'No Investment Account'
                ,'51'=>'Insufficient Funds'
                ,'52'=>'No Check Account'
                ,'53'=>'No Savings Account'
                ,'54'=>'Expired Card'
                ,'55'=>'Incorrect PIN'
                ,'56'=>'No Card Record'
                ,'57'=>'Transaction not permitted to Cardholder'
                ,'58'=>'Transaction not permitted on Terminal'
                ,'59'=>'Suspected Fraud'
                ,'60'=>'Contact Acquirer'
                ,'61'=>'Exceeds Withdrawal Limit'
                ,'62'=>'Restricted Card'
                ,'63'=>'Security Violation'
                ,'64'=>'Original Amount Incorrect'
                ,'65'=>'Exceeds withdrawal frequency'
                ,'66'=>'Call Acquirer Security'
                ,'67'=>'Hard Capture'
                ,'68'=>'Response Received Too Late'
                ,'75'=>'PIN tries exceeded'
                ,'76'=>'Reserved for Future Postilion Use'
                ,'77'=>'Intervene, Bank Approval Required'
                ,'78'=>'Intervene, Bank Approval Required for Partial Amount'
                ,'90'=>'Cut-off in Progress'
                ,'91'=>'Issuer or Switch Inoperative'
                ,'92'=>'Routing Error'
                ,'93'=>'Violation of law'
                ,'94'=>'Duplicate Transaction'
                ,'95'=>'Reconcile Error'
                ,'96'=>'System Malfunction'
                ,'98'=>'Exceeds Cash Limit'
                ,'A0'=>'Unexpected error'
                ,'A4'=>'Transaction not permitted to card holder, via channels'
                ,'Z0'=>'Transaction Status Unconfirmed'
                ,'Z1'=>'Transaction Error'
                ,'Z2'=>'Bank account error'
                ,'Z3'=>'Bank collections account error'
                ,'Z4'=>'Interface Integration Error'
                ,'Z5'=>'Duplicate Reference Error'
                ,'Z6'=>'Incomplete Transaction'
                ,'Z7'=>'Transaction Split Pre-processing Error'
                ,'Z8'=>'Invalid Card Number, via channels'
                ,'Z9'=>'Transaction not permitted to card holder, via channels'
            );
        }   

        function gtpay_thanks() {

            echo $this->response_codes(urldecode($_GET['desc']));



            if ($GET['desc'] != '00') {
                $this->generate_gtpay_form($_POST['txnref']);
            }
        }

        function parse_txn_ref_order_id($txnref) {
            $txnref = htmlentities($txnref);
            $txn_details = explode('_', $txnref);
            $marchant_id = $txn_details[1];
            $order_id = $txn_details[0];

            return $order_id;
        }   

        function process_payment( $order_id ) {
            $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

            return array(
                'result' => 'success',
                'redirect' => add_query_arg('order', $order->id, add_query_arg('key', $order->order_key, get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('pay'))))
            );
        }

        function receipt_page( $order ) {
            echo '<p>'.__('Thank you for your order, please click the button below to pay with GTPay.', 'woocommerce').'</p>';

            echo $this->generate_gtpay_form( $order );
        }

        function check_ipn_response() {
            if (isset($_POST['retRef'])) {
                @ob_clean();

                $_POST = stripslashes_deep($_POST);

                header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
                do_action("valid-gtpay-ipn-request", $_POST);
            }
        }

        function get_transaction_status($txnref) { 
            $return = false;
            $txnref = htmlentities($txnref);
            $txn_details = explode('a', $txnref);
            $marchant_id = $txn_details[1];
            //$hash_string = $marchant_id . $txnref . $this->hash_key;
            //$hash = hash('sha512', $hash_string);

            $endpoint = "https://ibank.gtbank.com/GTPay/Tranx.aspx";

            $endpoint .= '?mertid=' . $marchant_id . '&amount=' . $order_total . '&tranxid=' . $order_id . '&hash='.$hash;

            set_time_limit(0);

            $ch = curl_init($endpoint);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION ,1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,120);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER ,false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);

            $output = curl_exec($ch);
            $last_url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

            curl_close($ch);

            if ($last_url) {
                if ($url = parse_url($last_url)) {
                    if ($pairs = explode('&', $url['query'])) {
                    print_r($pairs); exit;
                        foreach ($pairs as $i=>$pair) {
                            $kv = explode('=', $pair);

                            $_GET[$kv[0]] = $kv[1];
                            $_REQUEST[$kv[0]] = $kv[1];

                            if ($kv[0] == 'resp') {
                                if ($kv[1] == '00') {
                                    $return = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return $return;
        }   

    }

    /**
     * Add the gateway to WooCommerce
     **/
    function add_gtpay_gateway( $methods ) {
        $methods[] = 'WC_GTPay'; return $methods;
    }

    add_filter('woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'add_gtpay_gateway' );
}


add_filter('plugins_loaded', 'sb_gtpay_init' );

?>
```

You can test out the website [here](http://augustcrush.com/shop).

Comment: This question is better suited to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: thanks. I'll send it there right away.

Comment: No, this is the right place. WPSE will send it right back as it isn't WordPress-core related. The problem is that you have kind of dumped your whole plugin hoping that someone will figure it out for you. Can you narrow it down and make the question more specific?

Comment: @user3072510 Looking at your code too.. not related to your display question... two things I notice is your reference to to response code 76 and use of Postilion, IF you receive that externally that wouldn't be applicable from Postilion. Also your if Last statement does not handle the Response Code of "10" which you would need to handle most likely or generate a reversal if a 10 is received if you do not support 10.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the default PayPal gateway. In the constructor there are 2 things being set up. First the notify URL that you will give to PayPal. This is where PayPal will send its IPN stuff.

```
$this->notify_url         = WC()->api_request_url( 'WC_Gateway_Paypal' );
```

If you track down the `api_request_url()` you find that if you are using permalinks your notify URL looks like : `www.mysite.com/wc-api/wc_gateway_paypal` or if not using permalinks your URL would be: `www.mysite.com?wc-api=wc_gateway_paypal`.

Then the constructor continues to attach a callback to the action hook that will be fired when your site receives a notification sent to the above URL.

```
// Payment listener/API hook
add_action( 'woocommerce_api_wc_gateway_paypal', array( $this, 'check_ipn_response' ) );
```

So when PayPal sends a response back the `check_ipn_response()` method handles it.

Keep in mind that this is just my best understanding based on reading the code. I've not actually tried using the API yet, even though I really want to.