# How to get the payment response url in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment, checkout

I have integrated pay4later api in my wordpress. I need to show the payment response details after payment success.

My Plugin file:

```
class WC_Pay4later extends WC_Payment_Gateway{
      add_action('woocommerce_api_' . strtolower( get_class( $this ) ), array($this, 'check_response' ) );

       function check_response()
       {
            /* Update Process*/ 
       }

    }
```

I set My return response url is:

```
www.mysite/pay4later/?wc-api=WC_Payment_GatewayPay4later_check_response.
```

When I call this it just displays 1.

How can I Fix this?

Comment: [This could be interesting for you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27331463/3730754) even if is not specific to pay4later. And [**this**](https://support.woothemes.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/202413166-check-out-with-API-url-to-forward-and-get-the-response) one too.

Comment: I reffered this . But I can't clear idea . I updated  the order details in check_response(). So can I this function via url .

Comment: Sorry, How can Call this function via url ?

Comment: It's specific to your source code. Each payment gateway have their own behaviors. Without source code access, it's impossible to help. During any transaction server gateway returns data. The response is dependent of that data. I don't have the technical doc for Pay4later gateway… And i don't know what is returned after transaction.

Comment: I need to get the gateway returns data  .

Comment: Can you show us the response data from gateway.? `echo json_encode( $_REQUEST  );` put this statment on your `check_response();` function. and tell us what you see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the skeleton structure of the `Pay4later` payment gateway for woocommerce.

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) { exit; }

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'wc_pay4later_init', 0 );

function wc_pay4later_init() {

    class WCPay4later extends WC_Payment_Gateway{

        public function __construct() {
            // Put your initialization scripts here
            // Which would be initializing merchan account info, secret keys, from this plugin's settings screen

            /* This would be your gateway return url */
            $this->callback = str_replace( 'https:', 'http:', home_url( '/wc-api/WCPay4later' )  );
            /* This action will redirect the gateway response to your 'check_pay_4_later_response' function */
            add_action( 'woocommerce_api_wcpay4later', array( $this, 'check_pay_4_later_response' ) );          
            /* This is the action where you prepare your digital form and submit to the gateway server */
            add_action('woocommerce_receipt_wcpay4later', array( $this, 'receipt_page') );          
        }

        function receipt_page( $order ) {
            echo '<p>'.__('Thank you for your order, please click the button below to pay with Pay 4 Later Gateway Service.', 'sark').'</p>';
            // prepare your digital form    
            echo $this -> generate_digital_form( $order );
        }

        function generate_digital_form( $order ) {
            // prepare and redirect to gateway server
        }

        function check_pay_4_later_response() {
            /* Update Process*/
        }

    }

    function woocommerce_add_pay_4_later_gateway( $methods ) {
        $methods[] = 'WCPay4later';
        return $methods;
    }   
    add_filter('woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'woocommerce_add_pay_4_later_gateway' );

}
```